# How to make text rotating scroll with jquery library.(needed example)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
$('.marquee').marquee({
  pauseOnHover: true
});
```

I dont know how to make text rotating scroll with jquery library. I dont know what jquery must i use. the text rotating scroll i'll use in html and css. im stuck on marquee.

Comment: Just use marquee html tag to do.

Comment: Might be you want this http://jsfiddle.net/c53am6rk/

Comment: no but scroll up for many text. and when i touch its stop

Comment: See this link if it helps you
http://www.thepetedesign.com/demos/jquery_super_simple_text_rotator_demo.html

Comment: Don't use marquee html tag, it is non standard and not supported by most browsers

Comment: how to make marquee without empty part

Answer (score 0):

Mighe be you want this

```html
<marquee><div>This is just example of marquee.</div></marquee>
```

Answer (score 0):

don't use marquee tag, this is a non-standard tag and it is not supported by most browsers: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee

If you are using the jQuery's Marquee plugin here are the exemples and samples codes you will need :

http://aamirafridi.com/jquery/jquery-marquee-plugin#examples